# How to get input values from javascript function so as to add them to database?

Tags: javascript, php, dom

i have a following code in form.js

```
     var c=0;
     var b=0;
     function myCreateFunction()
    {

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);


        cell1.innerHTML = c+1;
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input id='inp1' type='text' name='inpu1'>";
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input id='inp2' type='text' name='inpu2'>";
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input id='inp3'type='text' name='inpu3'>";
         cell5.innerHTML = "<input id='inp4' type='text' name='inpu4'>";
        cell6.innerHTML = "<input id='inp5' type='number' name='inpu5'>";


        c++;
        b=0;

     }
 }
```

now i want to get values from inpu1,inpu2,inpu3,inpu4,inpu5 and post them on to database using submit.php
How can this be done ??

Comment: You want to just post it to submit.php and with that reloading the page or do you want to submit it with JS / Ajax and so not to reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

This function will do it for you:

```
function post() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'submit.php', true );
    xhr.addRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = utf-8');
    xhr.send( 'inp1='+inp1.value+'&inp2='+inp2.value+'&inp3='+inp3.value+'&inp4='+inp4.value+'&inp5='+inp5.value );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit input data into database via PHP, you have to wrap all of your inputs in a form. Then on form submit, you tell the page what to do with the data via $_POST. You create a new mysqli connection, tell it what to insert, and run the query.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
<input name="inpu1" type="text"/>
//etc
<input type="submit" name="upload"/>

submit.php

$input1 = $_POST['inpu1'];
//establish mysqli connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,$database);
//create statement
$query = $mysqli->prepare ('INSERT INTO yourTable (data) VALUES (?)');
$query -> bind_param('s', $input1);
$query -> execute();
$query -> close()
$mysqli -> close();
```

This is obviously a very simple explanation, but with a little bit of reading you can be well on your way with inserting data into a database.